# Configure IDLE to use Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, python-idle

How do I make IDLE use UTF-8 as the default encoding for my Python files ?

There is no "Encoding" option in IDLE settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just put [special comment line](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html?highlight=coding#source-code-encoding) at the beginning of the Python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

Comment: you don't need it on Python 3 (it is the default). It assumes (correctly) that IDLE respects the encoding declaration.

Answer (score 0):

1) Navigate to the folder with your current version of python. Mine is:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources
2) View the python application package, as this is the IDLE.
3) You should see a file called `Info.plist` containing the line-
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
4) Here you can modify the encoding, keep in mind python dose not support all source encoding options.

Answer (score -3):

Python support following default encode type:

```
  **Python 2.x: ASCII**
  **Python 3.x: UTF-8**
```

If you are using python 2.x, then want to use UTF-8, Please add following code to your python file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import sys
 sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

This will override the default encoding type.

Comment: This is always a bad idea.  It breaks the standard libraries that expect the default to be *the default*.