# How to search regular expression in Hebrew (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, character-encoding, hebrew

I want to find something with re in Hebrew:

```
page = urlopen(url)
page_content = page.read()
founds = re.findall("מילים בעברית", page_content)
```

the error is:
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xec' in file C:/Users/User/untitled/milimBeIvrit.py on line 12, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Have you tried declaring an encoding as suggested in the linked PEP?

Comment: i tried this, the code run now but doesnt really work :(

Comment: Please check if [this solution of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32583571/3832970) works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `re` can handle `utf-8` strings.

You can change your default encoding if you want (but you don't have to)

```
>>> import sys
>>> import re
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

My default encoding is `ascii` and the following still works:

```
>>> a='אבא בא'
>>> results = re.findall("א", a)
>>> results
['\xd7\x90', '\xd7\x90', '\xd7\x90']
```

In order to print in a humanly readable format use `print`:

```
>>> for r in results:
...     print r

א
א
א
```

Note that [idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673342/configure-idle-to-use-unicode) has had some issues with the `utf8` handling, so one might consider to use an IDE such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Comment: thats doesnt work with ascii encode. how can i change it?

Comment: [sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-we-need-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

Comment: So you have other problem. Update your question accordingly/ask another question. As you can see this perfectly works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You do not say if this is Python 2 or 3.... If Python 2 - then you will have to play with encode and decode and there is no native Unicode.

However in Python 3 - this is how I would do this....
Sorry I can not good with Hebrew - small Arabic example instead.... but same principle.

```
import re
sentance='المتساقطة، تحت. من كردة مسارح قُدُماً ضرب, لان بشكل أكثر'
fs=re.search('لان', sentance)
if fs:
   print("Found it")
```

I have no idea what the arabic expression is - I pulled it from http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/_arabic.

I must stress - Unicode text is easy in Python3 but way way more pain in Python 2....

Exact the same as my arabic example - using Hebrew lore-ipsum (which I never knew existed until 30 seconds ago).

```
import re
sen2="רביעי ביולוגיה את אתה. מתן של מיזם המלצת ליצירתה, גם שכל חשמל אדריכלות למתחילים. צילום הבאים בעברית אחד בה. בדף או ריקוד מונחים לחשבון, ב הקהילה רב־לשוני זכר, וספציפיים האנציקלופדיה אל חפש. מתן אל נפלו עזרה אנתרופולוגיה."
fs=re.search('בדף',sen2)
if fs:
   print("Found it")
```

Looks ok to me....